# Validating multiple select box inside loop using laravel validation method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have multiple select box with same name inside loop in a form. I have added laravel validation to check select box selected or not. But validation error message is showing for all the select boxes. Please check image attached. Any help would be appreciated.

**cart.blade.php**

```
@forelse($carts as $key => $cart)
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4-booking1 form-group {{ $errors->has('guest.*.sleeps') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Sleep(s)</label>

    <select class="form-control form-control-booking1 jsBookCalSleep"  name="guest[{{ $cart->_id }}][sleeps]">
    <option value="">Choose Sleep(s)</option>
    @for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++)
       <option value="{{ $i }}" @if($i == $cart->sleeps) selected @endif>{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor
    </select>

    @if ($errors->has('guest.*.sleeps'))
         <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('guest.*.sleeps') }}</strong></span>
    @endif
</div> 
@empty
  <p>No bookings in your cart</p>
@endforelse
```

**CartController.php**

```
public function store(CartRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

**CartRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'guest.*.sleeps' => 'required|not_in:0'
        ];
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
@php
 $inputName='guest.'.$cart->_id.'.sleeps';
@endphp
@if ($errors->has($inputName))
     <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first($inputName) }}</strong></span>
@endif
```

I didn't tested it,
If not working let me know

Comment: Thank you. It is working. But small change (curley braces removed) from $inputName='guest.'.$cart->_id.'.sleeps';

Comment: Glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 0):

Solution: We can solve this issue by using two function. a.collect and b. contains. See the example below.

```
<select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker"
                                                name="generic_ids[]" data-live-search="true" multiple>
                                            <option value="">Select Generic</option>
                                            @foreach($generics as $generic)
                                                <option value="{{$generic->id}}"
                                                    @if(collect(app()->request->generic_ids)->contains($generic->id))
                                                    selected
                                                    @endif
                                                >{{$generic->title}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
```

**Code**

[image: Code Image]

**Output**
[image: Outout image]